# Call JS method from IF loop in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to call the JS method "returnToProposal" from an IF loop. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am getting the error

> Error: Unknown function returnToProposal. Check spelling

Code:
VF:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!returnToQuote}" value="{!IF(riskRec.size>0 ,riskRec[0].Name,'')}" rendered="{!AND(!displayCartButton,isOppStageStageW == FALSE)}" rerender="theForm,pgMsgs" status="counterStatus" oncomplete="{!IF(riskRec.size > 0,returnToProposal('riskRec[0].id','closeTabFlag}'),'')}" id="theCommandLink1"/>
```

JS:

```
function returnToProposal(id,closeFlag){        
    if(closeFlag == 'true'){
        window.open('/'+id,'_self');
    }
}
```

What works:

```
oncomplete="returnToProposal('{!riskRec[0].id}','{!closeTabFlag}');"
```

But it gives error when riskRec list is empty

Subscript is invalid because list is empty

Error is in expression

```
returnToProposal('{!riskRec[0].id}','{!closeTabFlag}');' in component <apex:commandLink> in page wctaxanalysis_v2
```

What I need:

```
oncomplete="{!IF(riskRec.size > 0,returnToProposal('riskRec[0].id','closeTabFlag}'),'')}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call a JS function from within a Visualforce merge field, so Visualforce thinks you're trying to call a controller function/value. To fix this, you need to use the merge field just within the expression to evaluate on the server:

```
oncomplete="returnToProposal('{!IF(riskRec.size > 0,riskRec[0].id,''}','{!closeTabFlag}')"
```

You also could use an actual boolean value:

```
oncomplete="returnToProposal('{!IF(riskRec.size > 0,riskRec[0].id,''}',{!closeTabFlag})"
```

And change your script:

```
function returnToProposal(id,closeFlag){
    if(closeFlag){
        window.open('/'+id,'_self');
    }
}
```